# Mongodb schema field validation not working in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to validate the registration number. It should only be alphanumeric. I don't understand why my validate function is not working. I have attached the schema below.

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const validator=require('validator');


const dvSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    registrationNumber:{
        type:String,
        validate(value){
            if(!validator.isAlphanumeric(value)){
                throw new Error('Registration number should be alphanumeric.')
            }
        },
        unique:true,
        required:true,
       
    },
    vehicleType:{
        type:String,
        enum:['bike','truck'],
        default:'truck'
        
    },
    city:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    activeOrdersCount:{
        type:Number,
        min:0,
        max:2,
        default:0
    }
})

module.exports=mongoose.model('deliveryVehicle',dvSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of your validate field is incorrect.

See the documentation on Mongoose.JS under [Custom Validators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators).

Change registrationNumber to the following.

```
registrationNumber: {
  type: String,
  validate:
    validator: function(value) {
      return validator.isAlphanumeric(value);
    },
    error: 'Registration number should be alphanumeric.'
  },
  unique:true,
  required:true,
},
```